# Rails - how to render a nested form partial in edit mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, partial-views, nested-forms

I'm trying to figure out how to render an edit link to a form which is nested.

I have models called Project and Potential Use. The associations are:

Project

```
has_many :potential_uses
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :potential_uses, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Potential Use

```
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
```

In my project show page, I render a view partial from my potential uses views folder. In that view, I render a link to allow content to be edited.

```
 <% @project.potential_uses.each do |pu| %>
            <p><%= pu.comment %></p>
             <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_potential_use_path(@project, pu), f: f %>
```

In my potential uses views folder, I have an edit view, with:

```
<%= render 'potential_uses_third_party_comments' %>
```

In my potential uses third party comments partial, I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for [ @project, @potential_use ] do |f| %>

            <%= f.error_notification %>

              <div class="form-inputs">
                    <%= f.input :comment, :label => 'Comment ', :input_html => {:rows => 5} %>

                </div>      

            <div class="form-actions">
             <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", :class => 'formsubmit' %>
            </div>
```

Something about this is wrong, because when I save it and try to use it, I get an error that says:

```
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007f8cb2f30188>:0x007f8cd171f448>
```

I understand from other posts, this error is solved by adding f: f to the end of the edit link. I already have that.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use rails fields_for method to render you nested from.

```
<%= f.fields_for :potential_uses do |pu| %>
   <%= render 'potential_uses_third_party_comments', f: pu %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_association '+ Add Potential Use(s)', f, :potential_uses, partial: "potential_uses_third_party_comments", class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: My objective is to allow a user to edit their existing comment - I'm not trying to make them create a new comment.

Comment: ok, than just pass id into list of permitted parameter (strong parameter).

Comment: I have: def potential_use_params
      params.fetch(:potential_use, {}).permit(:comment, :project_id, :user_id, :private_comment )
    end

Comment: do you mean the :id field should be added to that set of permitted attributes?

Comment: I tried adding :id to the strong params - but I get this error: undefined method `potential_use_path' for ... It points at this line of the form:  <%= simple_form_for [ @project, @potential_use ] do |f| %>

Comment: You need to just use form_for and add your primary key into string param.  
<%= form_for([ @project, @potential_use], html: { class: "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
and Strong Param like as per below.
params.require(
  :project
).permit(
  :comment,
  potential_uses_attributes: [
    :id
  ]
)

Comment: I already have the potential uses id in my strong params in the projects controller. the form works fine to create a new record, but I am now trying to let a user edit the record they created. That is giving an error that says: undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007fddfc51c458>:0x007fddf16ab450>

Comment: That error points to this line:               <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_potential_use_path(@project, pu), f: f %>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing..

```
<% @project.potential_uses.each do |pu| %>
   <p><%= pu.comment %></p>
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_potential_use_path(@project, pu), f: f %>
<% end %>
```

WHERE is your `f` variable defined? WHY add `f: f` to the `link_to` method?

`f` - i think, the `FormBuilder` object, The common case is to add `f: f` to the `render partials`, like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [ @project, @potential_use ] do |f| %>
  <%= render 'potential_uses_third_party_comments', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I added f: f to the edit link because I thought I was following advice from other posts. I'm not at all sure whether it's meant to be included or if it has been included correctly. I'm trying to render the edit link next to each existing comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please follw this url https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon you will get more idea for same.

Comment: Im not sure what to learn from these docs. I can see create and delete actions. I'm trying to figure out how to get edit working

Comment: just add id into strong params